# Strange regex exception with fullstop

Tags: java, regex

I am using

```
^(?i)(?=.*\bWORD_TO_FIND\b).*$
```

In this specific case I am trying to match "S.A.M."

This way it works:

```
^(?i)(?=.*\bs.a.m\b).*$
```

This way it doesn't:

```
^(?i)(?=.*\bs.a.m.\b).*$
```

Why does that fullstop brakes the match?

Comment: You don't need the lookahead assertion for this. And you should regex quote the find word(s). And you should use a boundary with qualification.  You could use a conditional boundary `"(?i)^.*(?(?=\\w)\\b)(?:" + regexQuote(text) + ")(?(?<=\\w)\\b).*$"` or, the best way is to use a whitespace boundary `"(?i)^.*(?<!\\S)(?:" + regexQuote(text) + ")(?!\\S).*$"`

Answer (score 1):

That is because of `\b` or `word boundary`.After `.` there is no `\b` or `word boundary` but after `m` there is.

```
^(?i)(?=.*\bs\.a\.m\.\b).*$

                    ^^
                  Here no word boundary so assertion or lookahead fails.
```

You should also be `escaping` `.` if you want to match `.`

Comment: Thanks, what other symbols should I escape?

Comment: @user2468425 all metacharacters that have special meaning in regex like `.*?{}` etc.

Comment: @user2468425 do accept if it worked for you

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work for me

Comment: @user2468425 what doesnt work?see here https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/13 for java you need to use `^(?i)(?=.*\\bs\\.a\\.m\\b).*$`